# SystemTap failed with error "WARNING: kbuild exited with status: 2"

Tags: module, makefile, kernel, systemtap, kbuild

I built a custom kernel 3.2-41, required kernel-debuginfo-common and kernel-debuginfo packages. I installed these packages on CentOS System with kernel 2.6.32-358. System booted fine with new kernel. I ran stap to list system calls and kernel function without any issue:

```
# stap -l 'syscall.*'
# stap -l 'kernel.function("*")'
```

However, running a simple stap script:

```
# stap -e 'probe "kernel.function("do_fork"){printf("fork is called\n")}'
```

return with errors:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target`/tmp/stap2QWXn/stap_12cd14bbeaab6bfcaac79c1830a62d98_710.src needed by /tmp/stap2QXn/stap_12cd14bbeaab6bfcaac79c1830a62d98_710.o 
Stop.
make: *** [_module/stap2QWXn] Error 2
WARNING: kbuild exited with status: 2
pass 4: compilation failed. Try again with another '--vp 001' option.
```

I untar the source of 3.2-41 under /usr/src/kernels/3.2-41. I did not install the kernel-headers-3.2.41.x86_64.rpm package considering it is attempting to overwrite /usr/include/ directories used by CentOS 2.6.32-258 kernel.  Do I need to install headers in /usr/include?  Would that be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this has nothing to do with kernel versions; maybe something went wrong with /tmp (full? permission problem?).
Try again with stap -k (keep tmpdir).  You should see a generated stap_..._src.c file and some others.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of gcc installed.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the verbosity level:

```
# stap -vvvv -e ...
```

This shows output of kbuild and any errors occuring.
In my case, the gcc used to compile the kernel did not match the gcc used by stap for the kbuild.